# Laravel MongoDB: Can we pull a particular subdocument with it's id?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-4

This is my collection subscribers

```
{
    "_id": "987654322",
    "subscriptions": [
        {
            "list_id": "13"
        },
        {
            "list_id": "12"
        }
    ],
    "offers": [
        {
            "campaign_id": 47,
            "title": "MasalaBox Awesome Sunday Offer",
            "description": "50% off on ALL online purchases!!",
            "thunbnailURL": "thumb/5m9Oav_images (4).jpg",
            "detailImageURL": "img/BpWyBT_original_290019_9BoDnY6NTBGpQq84atetEsA5Z.jpg",
            "detailedDescription": "Masalabox proudly presents the Awesome Sunday offer!! More info goes here. And some more here. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
            "targetURL": "http://www.altavista.com/",
            "end_date": "2015-02-28"
        }
    ]
}
```

All I want to do is: (1) search the collection for 'campaign_id' 47 in ALL subdocuments in field "offers". (2) If 'campaign_id'47 exists in a subdocument, I want to remove entire 47 document

```
 {
            "campaign_id": 47,
            "title": "MasalaBox Awesome Sunday Offer",
            "description": "50% off on ALL online purchases!!",
            "thunbnailURL": "thumb/5m9Oav_images (4).jpg",
            "detailImageURL": "img/BpWyBT_original_290019_9BoDnY6NTBGpQq84atetEsA5Z.jpg",
            "detailedDescription": "Masalabox proudly presents the Awesome Sunday offer!! More info goes here. And some more here. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
            "targetURL": "http://www.altavista.com/",
            "end_date": "2015-02-28"
        }
```

I used to push as given below

```
$offer = [
        'campaign_id' => $campaign->id,
        'title'       => $template->title,
        'description' => $template->description,
        'thunbnailURL' => $template->thunbnailURL,
        'detailImageURL' => $template->detailImageURL,
        'detailedDescription' => $template->detailedDescription,
        'targetURL'     => $template->targetURL,
        'end_date'      => $template->end_date,

    ];
    $subscribers= Subscription::where('offers.campaign_id', $campaign->id)->get();
    foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
        Subscription::where('_id',$subscriber->_id)->push('offers', array($offer));
    }
```

I think the following code could solve my issue, but, how can it be implemented in Laravel?

```
  dbh.subscription.update({"_id": "987654322"}, {"$unset":{"offers.campaign_id":47}},False,False)
```

I have been trying to solve this for few days and cannot figure it out.
Is it possible to perform in Laravel MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the Jenseggers package. But you will need to change the structure of the document in your collection if you're deep nesting data.

```
"offers": { 
        "47" : {
           "title": "MasalaBox Awesome Sunday Offer",
           "description": "50% off on ALL online purchases!!",
           "thunbnailURL": "thumb/5m9Oav_images (4).jpg",
           "detailImageURL": "img/BpWyBT_original_290019_9BoDnY6NTBGpQq84atetEsA5Z.jpg",
           "detailedDescription": "Masalabox proudly presents the Awesome Sunday offer!! More info goes here. And some more here. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
           "targetURL": "http://www.altavista.com/",
           "end_date": "2015-02-28"
    }
}
```

and then the query

```
Subscription::where('offers.47', 'exists', true)->unset('offers.47');
```

This should delete the specific subdocument. Although I recommend not go to deep with the nesting because it will be troublesome with searching.

If you go deeper it's probably better to create a new Subscription model and use a belongstomany - belongstomany relationship to connect both.

Best Regards,

Bdschr